# How to find WiFi adapter

Tags: wireless

I have Dell Inspiron 3520 with Ubuntu 17.10 installed but it will not connect wirelessly; however connects readily with Ethernet cable.
Does Ubuntu have a fix?

Comment: Please execute the command `lspci -knn | grep 0280 -A3` and append the results of that command to your question

Answer (score 0):

Check if the adapter is blocked by the system with

```
sudo rfkill list all
```

if it is try to unblock it with

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```